# if statement with quotient not working

Tags: java

I'm trying to make an if statement with a quotient.

totalGrades is a calculation of 5 numbers 
maxGrades is a calculation of the maximum grades of 5 classes ( maximum grades is always 39 )

I want to make a if statement that shows "Not enough points to graduate!" only if the totalGrades is below 5/6 of maxGrades

The quotient is not working and when I run it always prints Enough points to graduate even if totalGrades is below 5/6 of

```
if (totalGrades < 5 / 6)
meldingJaar = "Not enough points to graduate!";
else
meldingJaar = "Enough points to graduate!";
```

I tried this but this doesn't work

```
if (totalGrades % 82 <= maxGrades)
```

Comment: "if the totalGrades is below 5/6 of maxGrades" would be `if(totalGrades < maxGrades * 5/6)`, but you're also in java, so 5/6 is zero due to int division.

Comment: Are you using integers or floating point? Also, provide some concrete examples with numbers to demonstrate the problem.  "is not working" is insufficient information for anyone to help.

Comment: if(totalGrades < maxGrades * 5/6) worked for me, thanks Mike

Answer (score 1):

You're encountering integer division. Try `5f / 6` to invoke floating-point division.